# WordPress で add_image_size の使い所とは？

Tags: php, wordpress

現在、WordPressのテーマを作成しているのですが、画像サイズを登録する「add_image_size」は、どのような時に使うべきなのでしょうか？

高解像度ディスプレイに対応するため、imgタグには基本的に「等倍サイズ」「2倍サイズ」を指定しているのですが、テーマ内でユーザーが登録するであろう画像については、等倍サイズ・2倍サイズを作成するために、全て「add_image_size」を設定すべきなのでしょうか？

#### 登録するか迷っている画像（例）

- 通常投稿のサムネイル画像
- カスタムフィールドのプロフィールエリアに登録する画像
- カスタムフィールドで登録するスライダー画像
- 告知用のバナー画像   ...etc

#### imgタグのコーディング（例）

```php
<figure class="p-blogCard__thumb">
  <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : 
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'post_image'); 
    $image_url_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'post_image_2x');
    $image_alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
  ?>
  <img src="<?= $image_url[0]; ?>" srcset="<?= $image_url[0]; ?> 1x, <?= $image_url_2x[0]; ?> 2x" alt="<?= $image_alt; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
</figure>
```

#### add_image_sizeの指定（例）

```php
// 投稿サムネイル画像
add_image_size('post_image', 279, 177, true);
add_image_size('post_image_2x', 558, 354, true);
```